# Steps to Activate MultiCurrency for Sandbox only (Not Production)

Tags: sandbox, multi-currency, org, org-wide-defaults

I want to "Submit case" for multicurrency activation in **Sandbox only - not for the Production org**, how can I do that.

I have tried **Help & Training --> Submit Case**   ---Its taking me back to login.salesforce.com from where I am not able to login into my Sandbox/Test org !!!

Any Suggestions ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only log a case using **Help & Training** by logging in with your production credentials. You can however indicate you want the feature in your sandbox using the **Instance Type** picklist when creating the case.

Comment: Will it prevent activating Multicurrency in my Production ?

Comment: Yes, see https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003638&language=en_US

Comment: They have asked me to comment on case ! by saying that - "We are unable to accept screenshots or attachments through email. As an alternative, you can perform those functions by logging in to the Help site and attaching the materials to your case directly." What should I Do ? I never done this before –

Answer (score 4):

You need to log the case in your production org.  As indicated by others, you can choose the instance you want it activated in.  Just to ensure they do it on the right org, you can include the org ID of your sandbox instance in the case as well.

You can get the org Id by logging into your sandbox and navigating to

**Setup -> Company Profile -> Company Information**

Then you will see the ID for this Org.  Add that to the case to ensure they know exactly which org you want the feature activated in.

[image]

Comment: They have asked me to comment on case ! by saying that  - "We are unable to accept screenshots or attachments through email. As an alternative, you can perform those functions by logging in to the Help site and attaching the materials to your case directly." What should I Do ? I never done this before

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you can't log a case using sandbox credentials.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003785&language=en_US

So, you must have

1. production environment credentials
2. login to the salesforce production instance
3. and then from there goto Help & support and then log a case
4. select which instance you would like the desired feature to be activated